# form action, send data from the current form in the URL

Tags: php, forms

for the life of me cant remember how i should be doing this / if its possible.

I am creating a form that takes the user to another page but want to pass the value of the text box in the url.

so e.g:

```
<form action="newadvert.php?vrm=" class="newadvertform" method="post">
<input type="text" name="carvrm" class="carvrm"/>
<input type="submit" class="newadvertsubmit" value="Create Advert" />
</form>
```

How can i send the user to newadvert.php?vrm= THE ENTERED TEXT HERE

I need this to then get value on the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GET` method

```
<form action="newadvert.php" class="newadvertform" method="GET">
```

And rename `carvrm` to `vrm`

```
<input type="text" name="vrm" class="carvrm"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `GET` method and rename `carvrm` to `vrm`.

```
<form action="newadvert.php" class="newadvertform" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="vrm" class="carvrm"/>
<input type="submit" class="newadvertsubmit" value="Create Advert" />
</form>
```

When submitting the form, it'll go as http:///newadvert.php?vrm=

Answer (score 0):

change your form method from `post` to  `get`

Like this:

```
<form action="newadvert.php" class="newadvertform" method="get">
<input type="text" name="carvrm" class="carvrm"/>
<input type="submit" class="newadvertsubmit" value="Create Advert" />
</form>
```

you can get input value by :

```
$_REQUEST['carvrm']
```

or change input name to vrm :

```
  <form action="newadvert.php" class="newadvertform" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="vrm" class="carvrm"/>
    <input type="submit" class="newadvertsubmit" value="Create Advert" />
   </form>
```

now you can get input value by :

```
$_REQUEST['vrm']
```

doc: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="newadvert.php" class="newadvertform" method="get">
<input type="text" name="vrm" class="carvrm"/>
<input type="submit" class="newadvertsubmit" value="Create Advert" />
</form>
```